# Valgrind reports SIGILL in std::string::swap

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am using valgrind 3.16 to debug my program, and it reports illegal instruction in std::string::swap. The program is compiled on Ubuntu 18.04 with g++ 7.5.0.

```
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x62 0xF1 0xFE 0x8 0x6F 0x47 0x1 0xC5 0xF8 0x11
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=NONE
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
==392550== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x3fef89.
==392550==    at 0x3FEF89: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::swap(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /tmp/tmp.BnUAMaceSS/cmake-build-release-parallel-chameleon/release/lqf-tpch-query-dev)
==392550==    by 0x4F4CD0C: std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a website I can query instructions using the given OP code? I tried [this website](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html) but cannot find anything corresponding to `0x62 0xF1 0xFE ...`
2. Why would valgrind reports SIGILL in std library?

The code works well by itself. I also applied undefined,thread,leak and address sanitizer, and stack-check. They report no error. So I think the problem is from valgrind.

Comment: Most likely it is because your code has some sort of undefined behavior in it.  Can we get a [MRE]?

Comment: In addition to providing a [mcve], how are you compiling your program? If you aren't using some of the helping options, here's a bunch: `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -fstack-check`. They usually help to get a clearer picture of where things go awry.

Comment: 1) There may be, but it will do absolutely nothing to help you, because 2) you have a bug somewhere in your code. Just because a program crashes, like this, in the standard library, or even somewhere in one of your functions, doesn't mean that's where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The bug can be anywhere in the code that executed up until that point, which is why you must show a [mre] that accurately reproduces the  problem, before anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  The code works as expected and executes well by itself. It only reports error under valgrind. That's why I am thinking the problem is from valgrind. I am working on building a MWE

Comment: @Harper Did you try compiling with the options I provided? You can then run without valgrind to see if something odd happens. _Some_ libraries report leaks in `valgrind` that are deliberate (and can be safely suppressed) - but executing unknown instructions while swapping strings sounds really odd.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -fsanitize=address and -fsanitize=leak is part of my standard build process and there is no error under these two. I will now try the other two you mentioned.

Comment: Also make sure that you have `-lasan -lubsan` as the first libraries that you link with when you compile.

Comment: Just because "the code works as expected and executes well by itself" doesn't guarantee that it's bug free, and running code under valgrind changes runtime behavior sufficiently that undefined behavior in the existing code becomes visible. The opposite also frequently happens: code that crashes runs fine under valgrind. That's always a fun debugging session.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No error reported under all sanitizers and stack-check. I am still working on a MRE

Comment: BTW does anybody know what instruction the OP code represents? Are they just meaningless rubbish? Or am I really using some instructions not recognized by valgrind?

Comment: "_No error reported..._" - Ah, well, it was worth a try. I don't know about the instructions. Perhaps you've used some compiler options that produces code that's not recognized by valgrind and/or your target platform - or it can be a compiler bug. Will try it out when the MRE is finished (if it's soon) :-)

Comment: Please see my update. Although I failed to make a MRE, but after applying sanitizer the location of error changes and it helps me find the actual illegal instruction

Comment: The OP is right, in this case this is a limitation in Valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate @TedLyngmo's comments of applying sanitizers. Although the sanitizer itself does not give any error, after applying sanitizer the error location changes. Now it is pointing to some of my code base which uses AVX 512 instructions. When I replace those instructions Valgrind can run.

Although I am still not sure why applying sanitizer will have such effect, I would like to share this experience with those who may encounter similar errors in the future.

Comment: AVX 512 is still being worked on. If you are brave you could build Valgrind from source and apply the patch here https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383010

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1: convert opcode to assembly**

[This website](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2) can disassemble opcode to assembly online for x86 or x64. For the opcode in your question, insert `62 F1 FE 08 6F 47 01 C5 F8 11` (note that use **08 for 0x8**) to the text box under disassemble, then it outputs

```
Disassembly:
0:  62 f1 fe 08 6f 47 01    vmovdqu64 xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rdi+0x10]
7:  c5                      .byte 0xc5
8:  f8                      clc
9:  11                      .byte 0x11
```

So the instruction is `vmovdqu64`which is an AVX512 instruction.

Or you it can be hacked as following

```
$ cat instruct.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        asm(".byte 0x62, 0xF1, 0xFE, 0x8, 0x6F, 0x47, 0x1, 0xC5, 0xF8, 0x11");
        return 0;
}

$ gcc -c instruct.c
$ objdump -drwC -Mintel instruct.o

instruct.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
   4:   55                      push   rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   8:   62 f1 fe 08 6f 47 01    vmovdqu64 xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rdi+0x10]
   f:   c5 f8 11 b8 00 00 00 00         vmovups XMMWORD PTR [rax+0x0],xmm7
  17:   5d                      pop    rbp
  18:   c3                      ret
```

In order for valgrind to run a program with AVX512 instructions, one can compile the program with gcc flag `-mno-avx512f` as documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) which points out that extension instructions can be enabled with flag (e.g. `-mavx512f`) and disabled with a corresponding -`mno-` option.

Another way to use valgrind on a program with AVX512 instructions is to build Valgind from source and apply patches from [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383010#c51). Following are steps for it:

1. Clone valgrind source code

   ```
    $ git clone https://sourceware.org/git/valgrind.git
    $ cd valgrind
   ```
2. Download patches from [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383010#c51)

   Copy the patches to local files (e.g. **patch512-part1.patch inside
   folder
   valgrind**). Currently there are
   four patches, and they look quite messy due to the fact that the author
   keeps
   updating it (which is good) and obsoleting old ones. One should also apply the
   patches on top of right commit since new commits from valgrind master branch after the patches may break the
   build system. For example, up to now patches from comment 58, 73, 60 and 74 and
   on top of commit `b77dbefe72e4a5c7bcf1576a02c909010bd56991` can be compiled
   successfully.

   ```
   $ git reset --hard b77dbefe72e4a5c7bcf1576a02c909010bd56991
   ```
3. Apply patches

   ```
   $ patch -p1 < patch512-part1.patch
   $ patch -p1 < patch512-part2.patch
   $ patch -p1 < patch512-part3.patch
   $ patch -p1 < patch512-part4.patch
   ```
4. Compile valgrind

   ```
   $ ./autogen.sh
   $ ./configure  --prefix=<install-path>
   $ make
   $ make install
   ```